# Excel VBA: If statement to copy/paste into a new worksheet then delete rows of what was copied

Tags: vba, excel

Just started learning VBA today to try to make life a bit easier at my new job. I'm essentially trying to look for every instance where column E has the letter "a" copy and paste it into a newly created worksheet called "Aton" then delete the original rows with the "a"s.

I tried to modify the solution found here: [VBA: Copy and paste entire row based on if then statement / loop and push to 3 new sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44252216/vba-copy-and-paste-entire-row-based-on-if-then-statement-loop-and-push-to-3-n#)

When I changed the above solution to make this line "If wsSrc.Cells(i, "E").Value = "a" Then" that's when I run into problems.

```
    Sub Macro3()
        'Need "Dim"
        'Recommend "Long" rather than "Integer" for referring to rows and columns
        'i As Integer
        Dim i As Long
        'Declare "Number"
        Dim Number As Long
        'Declare a variable to refer to the sheet you are going to copy from
        Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
        Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet
        'Declare a variable to refer to the sheet you are going to copy to
        Dim wsDest As Worksheet
        'Declare three other worksheet variables for the three potential destinations
        Dim wsEqualA As Worksheet
        'Create the three sheets - do this once rather than in the loop
        Set wsEqualA = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        'Assign the worksheet names
        wsEqualA.Name = "Aton"

        'Determine last row in source sheet
        Number = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To Number


        'Determine which destination sheet to use
        If wsSrc.Cells(i, "E").Value = "a" Then
            Set wsDest = wsEqualA
        Else

        End If

        'Copy the current row from the source sheet to the next available row on the
        'destination sheet
        With wsDest

            wsSrc.Rows(i).Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End With

        'Delete row if column E has an a
        If wsSrc.Cells(i, "E").Value = "a" Then
            Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Else

        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you shared doesn't match the description of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking to your code, you have three issues

- when deleting rows you have to loop backwards and avoid skipping rows
- you’re copying and (trying to) deleting rows outside the ‘If wsSrc.Cells(i, "E").Value = "a"‘ block, hence regardless of current row “i” column E value
- you don’t want to delete currently selected range rows, but currently loop “i” row

Putting it all together here’s the correct relevant snippet;

```
Set wsDest = wsEqualA 'set target sheet once and for all outside the loop
For i = Number To 1 Step -1 'Loop backwards 
    If wsSrc.Cells(i, "E").Value = "a" Then
        'Copy the current row from the source sheet to the next available row on the destination sheet
        With wsDest
            wsSrc.Rows(i).Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)   'Copy wsSrc current “i” row and paste it to wsDest
            wsSrc.Rows(i).Delete   'Delete wsSrc current “i” row
        End With
    End If
Next
```

As a possible enhancement, you could swap the sheets references in the “With...End With” block, since it’s more effective to reference the mostly “used” one:

```
        With wsSrc
            .Rows(i).Copy wsDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)   'Copy wsSrc current “i” row and paste it to wsDest
            .Rows(i).Delete   'Delete wsSrc current “i” row
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify which sheet the original values are on. Change `Sheet` on the line `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` to your sheet name.

---

1. Create new sheet and set objects
2. Create range to loop through, `LoopRange` (E2 down to last row in column)
3. Loop through `LoopRange`. If criteria is met, add the cell, `MyCell`, to a collection of cells (`TargetRange`)
4. If the `TargetRange` is not empty (meaning your criteria was met at least once) then copy header from `ws` to `ns`
5. Copy `TargetRange` from `ws` to `ns`
6. Delete `TargetRange` from `ws`

The benifit if using `Union` to collect cells is that you avoid many iterations of `copy/paste/delete`. If you have 50 cells in your range that meet your criteria, you will have 50 instance each for `copy/paste/delete` for a grand total of **150 actions**.

Using the `Union` method, you will just have 1 instance for each action for a grand total of **3 actions** which will boost run time.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Learning()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ns As Worksheet: Set ns = Worksheets.Add(After:=(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)) 'ns = new sheet
ns.Name = "Aton"

Dim LoopRange As Range, MyCell As Range, TargetRange As Range

Set LoopRange = ws.Range("E2:E" & ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each MyCell In LoopRange 'Loop through column E
    If MyCell = "a" Then
        If TargetRange Is Nothing Then 'If no range has been set yet
            Set TargetRange = MyCell
        Else 'If a range has already been set
            Set TargetRange = Union(TargetRange, MyCell)
        End If
    End If
Next MyCell

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Not TargetRange Is Nothing Then 'Make sure you don't try to copy a empty range
        ws.Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy ns.Range("A1") 'copy header from original sheet
        TargetRange.EntireRow.Copy ns.Range("A2")
        TargetRange.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        MsgBox "No cells were found in Column E with value of 'a'"
    End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You could also just filter `Column E` by `a` and then copy/delete visible cells.

Comment: Hey I appreciate the help but it seems to get stuck on Dim ns As Worksheet: Set ns = Worksheets.Add(After:=(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)) 'ns = new sheet.  Method 'add' of object 'Sheets' failed

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `ActiveSheet`, it can cause multiple problems. If `sheet1` is not your source worksheet then change it to meet your needs. I prefer using a filter, as urdearboy suggested, which dosn't require a loop and is faster. I always try to keep the code simple, so try this...

```
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Aton"

    With Sheet1.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="a", Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Aton").Range("A1")
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter
    End With
```